# Cannot select option on select generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this method which iterate over a collection of object:

```
$.each(obj.actions, function (i, act) {
     generate_action(i+1);
     $('.section-actions[data-id=' + i + 1 + '] > option[value='+act.id_section_to+']').prop('selected', true);
});
```

essentially there are two object with the following properties:

```
{id: "1", id_section: "1", id_section_to: "2", id_criteria: "1", id_parameter: "1"}
{id: "2", id_section: "2", id_section_to: null, id_criteria: "3", id_parameter: "2"}
```

the method `generate_action` create a new select:

```
generate_action = function(data_id)
{ 
    var select = '<select class="form-control section-actions" data-id="' + data_id + '"><option value="">END</option><option value="2">GO TO SEC 2</option></select>';

   $('#select-container').append(select);
}
```

the select is added correctly to the container, after this process in the main loop I'm trying to set the value of the option which is already available but the code doesn't works.

I can't get the option with value `2` selected in the first `select`, of course in the second `select` it works because the first option have already a null value.

Now, I tried this code after the loop:

```
$('.section-actions[data-id="1"] > option[value=2]').prop('selected', true);
```

and this has worked. What I did wrong? I'm banging my head since yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to assign the function to a variable.

Change:

```
generate_action = function(data_id)
```

To

```
function generate_action(data_id)
```

**OR:** Simply declare and assign the function before `$.each()`

```js
var obj = {actions:[ {id: "1", id_section: "1", id_section_to: "2", id_criteria: "1", id_parameter: "1"},
{id: "2", id_section: "2", id_section_to: null, id_criteria: "3", id_parameter: "2"}]}

var generate_action = function(data_id)
{ 
    var select = '<select class="form-control section-actions" data-id="' + data_id + '"><option value="">END</option><option value="2">GO TO SEC 2</option></select>';
   $('#select-container').append(select);
}

$.each(obj.actions, function (i, act) {
     generate_action(i+1);
     $('.section-actions[data-id=' + i + 1 + '] > option[value='+act.id_section_to+']').prop('selected', true);
});
$('.section-actions[data-id="1"] > option[value=2]').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-container"></div>
```

Comment: mm the strange thing is that your solution not works for me, how can I investigate further?

Comment: @LazyStuff, Is it working in the snippet as you expect? Is there any error in console?

Comment: yep your solution works in the snippet, but when I implemented in the code nothing has changed, I guess it's not a problem related to store the function into a variable

Comment: @LazyStuff, then the best option is to debug your code in your actual environment...

Comment: found it, that was really simple. I think I need to take some rest

Answer (score 0):

Use `[data-id=' + (i + 1) + ']` instead of `[data-id=' + i + 1 + ']` like below.

```
$('.section-actions[data-id=' + (i + 1) + '] > option[value='+act.id_section_to+']').prop('selected', true);
```

You can see whats wrong with your code below.

```js
var i = 1, act = { id_section_to: 1 };
console.log('If you use [data-id= + i + 1 + ] then it will generate following');
console.log('.section-actions[data-id=' + i + 1 + '] > option[value='+act.id_section_to+']');
console.log('If you use [data-id= + (i + 1) + ] then it will generate following');
console.log('.section-actions[data-id=' + (i + 1) + '] > option[value='+act.id_section_to+']');
```